# Unable to load css/js files in a spring project

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, external-js

I have tried 2 ways to load `external css or js files` in my spring project but neither of them is working fine.

Home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />//NOT LOADING
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/style.css"/>" />//Not loading Method tried 1
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">//Not loading Method tried 2
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">      </script>
```

Comment: is `resources` folder under `WebContent` or any equivalent Web root directory? or under src folder?

Comment: Without knowing where your files are in your project, and what your spring configuration is, it's quite hard to give any answer. Read the documentation and look for "static resources".

Comment: @Yogi Yes resources folder is inside webcontent only..

Comment: you have to add  context of application with link like context is "myapp" then your url should be <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="/myapp/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />